# Left Outer join on a many to one relationship in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

In my xx.hbm.xml file I have written this:

```
<class name="com.xxx.model.PosDataBDEntryBean" table="BD_Trans">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="native"></generator>
    </id>
    <many-to-one name="itemCode" class="com.xxx.model.BDMasterBean" fetch="join" lazy="false">
        <column name="item_code"/>
    </many-to-one>
    <property name="transDate" column="trans_date" />
     </class>
```

And I have another table bd_item which has relationship with com.xxx.model.BDMasterBean class and itemcode as primary key.

And in my DAO class I have written this lines of code:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PosDataBDEntryBean.class);
         criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("transDate",cDate)).add(Restrictions.eq("location", "BD"));
        posBDEntryGridList = criteria.list();
```

I have two tables, bd_item and bd_trans. bd _item has item_codes without decimal nos and bd_trans has items having decimal and non decimal nos. How  can I joi these two tables to get matching rows. I am getting exception "No row with given Identifier exists :com.xxx.model.BDMasterBean#1189.0". How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid, you'd better clean this up in the database. 
You have to make sure that only integer values are allowed in the ID columns. (You'll also have to convert the existing values in the database. If you don't know how to do that properly, that will be other question).

However, I understand it may not possible for you to modify the database schema.
In that case, you'll have to convert the id value manually and query BDMasterBean for the given item_code.